# Slick 3.0.0 Aggregate Queries

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to do a complex querying on two tables. They look like below:

Table1:

```
  id:
  name:
  table2Id:
  version:
```

Table2:

```
  id:
  comments:
```

Assuming that I have the appropriate Slick classes that represents these tables, I'm trying to get all the elements from Table1 and Table 2 that satisfies the following condition:

```
Table1.table2Id === Table2.id and max(Table1.version)
```

I tried the following:

```
val groupById = (for {
  elem1 <- table1Elems
  elem2 <- table2Elems if elem1.id === elem2.id
} yield (elem1, elem2)).groupBy(_._1.id)
```

I know that I have to map the groupById and look for the max version, but I'm not getting the syntax right! Any help?

What I need is effectively Slick equivalent of the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t t1 
WHERE t1.rev = (SELECT MAX(rev) FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate:

```
SELECT * from t t1 WHERE t1.rev = (SELECT max(rev) FROM t t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)
```

Try either of the following:

```
val q1 = for{
  t < table1 if t.rev === (
    table2.filter(_.id === t.id).map(_.rev).max
  )
} yield t

val q2 = table1.filter{t=> t.rev === (
  table2.filter(_.id === t.id).map(_.rev).max
)}.map(identity)
```

**EDIT based on comment:**

```
val q = (for{
  t1 < table1; t2 <- table2 if t1.id === t2.id
} yield t1).orderBy(_.version.max).reverse.take(1)
```

Comment: There is no revision field in table2, so the map(_.rev) does not work? May be my question might be wrong. Sorry for that! If you notice the Table structure, the version is present in Table1 and not in Table2. So what I want effectively is the max version in Table1 for the given id that has a match in Table2

Comment: I modified my other post, which is slightly a different requirement on what I'm trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407289/slick-2-1-0-filter-max-version-in-a-table Could you please take a look and suggest?

Comment: Your both queries do not work. Do you have a better idea? Suggestions?